# Play local audio in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to play local audio in React using hooks. Application will be deployed later to some server.

Application folder consists of the following:

- *index.html*
- *index.css*
- *index.js*
- *audio folder* with *first.mp3* and *second.mp3*

It looks like this:
[image: app image]

I have added screenshot because without CSS it wouldn't we clear what I need to accomplish. (just two simple numbers would be printed in div). [Codepen link (with CSS)](https://codepen.io/amar-husika/pen/GRBqKmN)

So I should play sound when these *Box* components are clicked.

Here's 'index.js' file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import "./index.css"
const sounds = [
  {
    key: "1",
    mp3: "./audio/first.mp3",
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    mp3: "./audio/second.mp3",
  }
];
const App = () => {
  const [keys, setKeys] = useState([
    "1",
    "2"
  ]);
  return (
      <div id="display" className="display">
        {sounds.map((sound, id) => {
          return <Box text={sound.key} audio={sound.mp3} />;
        })}
      </div>
  );
};
const playSound=(props)=>{
  return(
     props.audio.current.play;
  )
}
const Box = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="box" onClick={playSound(props)}>
      {props.text}
      <audio src={props.audio} className="clip" id={props.text}/>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Problem here is `props.audio.current.play;`. It doesn't play the sound.

I tried to `console.log(props.audio)` and it prints correctly for ex. `./audio/first.mp3`

Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: I think you should create an instance of the audio by taking the audio URL and try playing/pausing that. For example: let audioEl = new Audio(audioURL); audioEl.play()

Comment: I don't have audio URL. I made it locally in a software. Is there any way to do it locally and that should work also when app deploys online?

Comment: Yeah you just need to provide the accessible/valid audio URL. Or for testing purpose just put the audio in the public folder?

Comment: could you run it locally with 'npm install' and 'npm start'?

Comment: Oh yes  shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just reach out to me in case you still have this issue, I'm happy to help. Thanks! 

Comment: It is not possible to put it inside public folder on codepen, or I don't know how to do it

Comment: Oh! If you want to try the solution maybe you can use this URL: https://file-examples.com/storage/fe8a7837bf63ad8783d6a5d/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3?

Answer (score -1):

I can help you out by providing a general idea:

```
let audioEl = new Audio(audioUrl);

// Play
audioEl.play();

// Pause
audioEl.pause();

// Set current time
audioEl.currentTime = 0;
```

Comment: question is about local file

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem, can you please try this. See you can try this on local and by putting the file in the public folder. Can you please provide me the sandbox link where you're trying to implement this?